# Why we use Val for Accumulators and not Var in scala?

Tags: apache-spark, scala-spark

Why we use **Val** instead of **Var** for *accumulators*?  If its like a counter that's shared across for multiple executor nodes to just update/change it, then it means reassigning a Val right?

`val accum = sc.longAccumulator("New Accumulator")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, we are instantiating a Class of LongAccumulator. Your logic is not wrong, but the object that we are storing in the `accum` is static, but inside this object, we have two `var` values. `sum` and `count` the object is immutable. But the values inside of it are not.

You can see the details of the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.scala#L315).

Comment: Fantastic ... The moment I saw the two variables, Sum and Count, It cleared my doubt... I should look at the actual class going forward then .. Really appreciated.. :) Thanks thiago ..